# Connect snap interfaces

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, snap, camera

I am trying to install Zoom video conferencing application in Ubuntu 18.04. I searched for Zoom in Ubuntu Software and found the screen to install Zoom client. The screen suggested that I connect 5 interfaces after installing Zoom including audio-record, camera, etc. How do I connect these interfaces in Zoom?

[image: zoom-client snap package]

Each time I try to start Zoom it crashes.

Comment: "I will not list the interfaces." If we are meant to guess at what the program is telling you to do, how do you expect us to help you? If, ***for some reason***, Zoom is displaying personal information or sensitive data inside of the interface list, consider censoring it with more generic naming schemes.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information.  To install Zoom one must copy and paste 5 interfaces into the terminal.  The first one was:  "sudo snap connect zoom-client:audio-record".    I was able to complete all 5, but Zoom still does not work for me.  Each time I try to start Zoom it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

For proper operation please connect the following interfaces after installing the Zoom client in Ubuntu with `sudo snap install zoom-client`. Run the following commands from the terminal.

```
sudo snap connect zoom-client:audio-record
sudo snap connect zoom-client:camera
sudo snap connect zoom-client:hardware-observe
sudo snap connect zoom-client:network-manager
sudo snap connect zoom-client:system-observe
```

To stop Zoom client from crashing when opening, launch Zoom client from the terminal with a higher than default scheduling priority instead of launching it by clicking on its icon in the Dash. `nice` value range is -20 to +19 where -20 is highest, 0 default and +19 is lowest. By default when a program is launched in Linux, it gets launched with the `nice` scheduling priority of 0.

```
nice -n -10 snap run zoom-client
```

Another way to prevent Zoom from crashing is to close all applications that use a lot of RAM and GPU resources before launching Zoom including the web browser, video player and IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

I installed ubuntu 18.04 and installed Zoom plus made a video to show you how to install Zoom.You shouldn't have any problems.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kTyKaSS9EzRiRRJzD365Hgr6ecgWRmGa

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I pasted the lines into the terminal as suggested.  (after installing Zoom).  Unfortunately the process did not work as Zoom crashes each time I try to launch.  The screen is filled with dashed lines and locked up.  I have to push the power button to restart.  Any suggestions anyone?  I do have Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

you can download it from the official web page https://zoom.us/download
after downloaded, (example: zoom_amd64 Version 5.1.422789.0705.deb) double click the file or right click to open with software installer, and it will install automatic for you
it works for me ubuntu 18.04 lts 20 jul 2020

for update zoom, Zoom provides a pop-up notification when there is a new mandatory or optional update or you check manual from the menu